# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent Model Relationship not working, Returns NULL

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5, model, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and am struggling with this:

Database - MSSQL existing DB schema cannot be modified as other software depends on it. (not sure if this is a problem or not)

Model/Table setup:
     INFO_ALL Table - ID is primary key
     PERSON Table - ID is foriegn key

ID's are hex values and I notice eloquent removes the 0x from the start of the value and am not sure if this is causing the relationship to fail or not. example: in the DB I see 0x123456789 in my returned eloquent data I see 123456789

Person Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
protected $table = 'PERSON';
protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
public $incrementing = false;
public $timestamps = false;

    public function info_all(){

        return $this->belongsTo(Info_All::class, 'ID', 'ID');
        }
}
```

Info Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Info_All extends Model
{
protected $table = 'INFO_ALL';
protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
public $incrementing = false;
public $timestamps = false;

    public function person(){

       return $this->hasOne(Person::class, 'ID', 'ID');

    }
}
```

How I am testing the relationship:

```
php artisan tinker
$person = App\Person::first();
$person->info;
NULL

php artisan tinker
$info= App\Info::first();
$info->person;
NULL
```

I know this relationship exists in the DB and I can manuualy get them together with a query but the relationship feature of this framework would really be nice to get figured out.

Beign new to Laravel there are a few things I am unsure about, like if the third argument in the realationship is neccesary since I am declaring the $primaryKey.  I declared the $primarykey in the first model because I assummed it is case sensative and my table has ID not id.  That being said, I have been stuck on this for a couple days and feel like I have tested everything in every different combination.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your relation is defined incorrectly. Try by adding following relation:

Person Model

```
public function info()
{
   return $this->hasOne(Info_All::class, 'ID', 'ID');
}
```

Info_All model

```
public function person()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class, 'ID', 'ID');
}
```

Then try it out in tinker:

```
$person = App\Person::first();
$person->info;
```

I am not sure but if eloquent removes the `0x` from the start of the value then it can also cause the problem.

Try by removing `0x` from your tables.

Comment: There are more ID's in the info table than the Person table.  Info can exist (username and privileges) without a person (picture, name address).  It's a little odd but its an existing DB with a dependency on existing software that I am trying to add features to with a web app.   So I believe my relationship is correct.   The actual table names are seemingly random names so I change them to Person and Info in the questions to make it easier to read but I may have made it a bit confsuing.

Comment: When a table has an FK then in relation you have to define a `belongsTo` method. Please read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) for more info.

Comment: Yes, my description of the table is incorrect but the code had the correct relationship info. Info hasOne

Comment: Person belongto info

Comment: Then please make sure you provide correct information in the question otherwise, it will not helpful for anybody.

Comment: Question has been updated but does it really matter?  How does Eloquent work? If I pull a record with an ID that matches in the two tables will the relationship work even if the belongsTo hasOne is reversed?